# Access to the path 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Kentico12_2\CMS\App_Data\CMSTemp' is denied

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, kentico, kentico-12, kentico-mvc

I am trying to upload image via administration interafe of Kentico. I am getting this error when I try upload a image.

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UAeT9.jpg)

What I tried so far;

1. I changed wwwroot folder security properties, and I gave full control acccess to IIS_IUSR,
2. I tried to create CMSTemp folder by myself.

Any other suggestions besides these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The user running the application pool should be the user that has read/write access to those folders, not just the IIS_IUSR user.  If your application pool is NOT using Application Pool Identity then IIS_IUSR will not work for folder permission and you'll have to select the individual network user you have assigned in the application pool.